# How to create a ListBox item control and bind a complex type to

Tags: winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml, winui-3

I have the following custom control,

```cs
public sealed class MediaFileItemControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MediaFileProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MediaFile), typeof(StorageFile), typeof(MediaFileItemControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MediaFileItemControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MediaFileItemControl);
    }

    public StorageFile MediaFile
    {
        get => (StorageFile)GetValue(MediaFileProperty);
        set => SetValue(MediaFileProperty, value);
    }
}
```

the following style for it,

```xml
<!-- Generic.xaml -->
<Style TargetType="controls:MediaFileItemControl" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:MediaFileItemControl">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding MediaFile.Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding MediaFile.Path}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and lastly, I want to use it within a `ListBox`, something like:

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.MediaFiles, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="win_storage:StorageFile" xmlns:win_storage="using:Windows.Storage">
            <controls:MediaFileItemControl MediaFile="{x:Bind}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

However, when I build the project, I get the following error in `Generic.xaml`

```
The XAML Binary Format (XBF) generator reported syntax error '0x80004005'
```

Where is the syntax error and what is the right way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Simply define Setter.Value as `<ControlTemplate><StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"><TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" /><TextBlock Text="{Binding Path}" /></StackPanel></ControlTemplate>`

Comment: This does not seem right. Let's assume that I have more then one property in the custom control, how will the style know `Name` is for which property? By the way, I tried what you suggested before. The syntax error goes away, but the binding still does not work. The list item is there but there is nothing visual.

Comment: I don't know how you tried, but it does work for me. Please post a reproducing project so we can fix it.

Comment: I apologise. I missed that in your suggestion you replaced `TemplateBinding` with `Binding` as well. Yes, this works. I am a bit confuse though because of the magic (dynamic binding) this entails. Is there a way to use `x:Bind` instead of `Binding` to get compile time check?

Comment: My guess is that `TemplateBinding` doesn't support multi-part paths. It's typically used to bind a property of a template part to the property of the templated control and it's the first time I see someone trying to bind it to a property of the property. Usually a `binding` or `x:Bind` to a list item is defined within a `DataTemplate` and a custom control should not be aware what item model someone is binding it to. You could put your `MediaFileItemControl` in the `DataTemplate` but, make MFIC derive from `ContentControl` and put the `StackPanel` + the bindings in the `ListBox.ItemTemplate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[x:Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) has lots of issues that are quite difficult to overcome: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2508

But you can use a `ContentControl` that points to a `DataTemplate`. So in your case, you can write it like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    x:Class="MyWinUIApp.ResourceDictionary1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyWinUIApp"
    xmlns:storage="using:Windows.Storage">

    <DataTemplate x:Key="StorageFileTemplate" x:DataType="storage:StorageFile">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="local:MediaFileItemControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource StorageFileTemplate}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Note I've create a custom `ResourceDictionary` as it doesn't seen to work in the App.xaml one for another mysterious reason. Make sure you create one with a code-behind to support x:Bind as explained here: [Resource dictionaries with {x:Bind}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#resource-dictionaries-with-xbind)

If you don't want that complexity, you can still use the ole `Binding` markup extension wich often works where the so-called "better" `x:Bind` fails:

```
<Style TargetType="local:MediaFileItemControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. I think I will avoid the complexity and go with the good old `Binding`. Although I think my requirement (I have more to do with the control than a single property) is better achieved by a User Control.